# Kafka sprint plugin is not distributing all partitions

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

Let's say the Kafka topics (my-topic) has 8 partitions and I am having a listener group (my-topic-group) of 8 to 10 different process running on different machine. A particular partition (my-topic-2) is not being consumed by any of the listeners.

**Here is the code for Kafa Producer (Jar-1)**

```
import org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer;
import org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.ProducerRecord;

KafkaProducer producer ;
.....


producer.send(new ProducerRecord('my-topic', student_id % 8, null, payload));
```

**Here is the code for Kafa listener config in spring (Jar-2)**

```
@EnableKafka
@Configuration
public class SpringBootKafka {

    @Bean
    public Map<String, Object> consumerConfigs() {
        Map<String, Object> props = new HashMap<>();

        String servers ;
        .....

        props.put("bootstrap.servers", servers);
        props.put("group.id", "my-topic-group");
        props.put("key.deserializer", StringDeserializer.class);
        props.put("value.deserializer", StringDeserializer.class);
        props.put("auto.offset.reset", "earliest");

        return props;
    }

    @Bean
    public ConsumerFactory<String, String> consumerFactory() {
        return new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<>(consumerConfigs());
    }

    @Bean
    public KafkaListenerContainerFactory<ConcurrentMessageListenerContainer<String, String>> kafkaListenerContainerFactory() {
        ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, String> factory = new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<>();
        factory.setConsumerFactory(consumerFactory());
        return factory;
    }
}
```

**Kafka listener (Jar-2)**

```
@Component
public class EventsReceiver {
    @KafkaListener(topics = "my-topic")
    public void receive(ConsumerRecord<String, String> consumerRecord) {

        String message = consumerRecord.value();

    }
}
```

Initially the Jar-2 was deployed in 1 machine (docker) and slowly we increased the number of pod to 10. None of the pod listening to the **my-topic-partition-2**. And more than one is listening to **my-topic-partition-7**. So I am missing some kafka events in the listener.

Comment: Why are you using `student_id % 8` yourself? The default partitioner already does a modulo on the total topics

Comment: Not sure why, but that is not my code. I am just consuming from the kakfa.

Comment: It is part of the code you pasted in the question... What do you mean?

Comment: In any case, how do you know messages are even within partition 2? If you're not consuming, then you need to check data is actually there

Comment: Jar-1 is not my code, jar-2 is my code. After spring-boot reloading, I don't see any process connected to partition-2(from the logger). I wrote another code in Perl to read all partition and printed data & partition information, which has all the data (including partition-2). I am assuming there is something wrong in spring config.

Comment: As long as you are not manually assigning partitions, the consumer should read them all. And I doubt it's a Spring config issue, but you're welcome to try the same consumer properties in non-Spring code

Comment: did you check partition 2 has messages

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue, it is running in 2 different data centre and both points to the same Kafka cluster. The partition-2 is assigned to the second data centre.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the logs; you should see something like this as instances come up:

```
Instance 1

partitions assigned: [so51673658-2, so51673658-1, so51673658-4, so51673658-3, so51673658-6, so51673658-5, so51673658-8, so51673658-7, so51673658-9, so51673658-0]
partitions revoked: [so51673658-2, so51673658-1, so51673658-4, so51673658-3, so51673658-6, so51673658-5, so51673658-8, so51673658-7, so51673658-9, so51673658-0]
partitions assigned: [so51673658-2, so51673658-1, so51673658-4, so51673658-3, so51673658-0]
partitions revoked: [so51673658-2, so51673658-1, so51673658-4, so51673658-3, so51673658-0]
partitions assigned: [so51673658-4, so51673658-6, so51673658-5]

Instance 2

partitions assigned: [so51673658-6, so51673658-5, so51673658-8, so51673658-7, so51673658-9]
partitions revoked: [so51673658-6, so51673658-5, so51673658-8, so51673658-7, so51673658-9]
partitions assigned: [so51673658-8, so51673658-7, so51673658-9]

Instance 3

partitions assigned: [so51673658-2, so51673658-1, so51673658-3, so51673658-0]
```